# How to give table name as variable in for loop select statement in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  T_TABLE_N := UPPER(TABLE_N);
   FOR ATTRIBUTE_ IN (SELECT HEADER_NAME FROM T_TABLE_N
                      GROUP BY HEADER_NAM )
```

Here, I use the T_TABLE_N table as a variable. But it wasn't taken as a table

How to solve this problem

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? These are different database systems.

Comment: Oracle **@ThorstenKettner**

Comment: What you are loking for is called dynamic SQL. But the need for doing this may indicate a bad data model. Maybe you want to explain why you need this, so we may be able to hint on a better desgn.

Comment: Then it is dynamic SQL. If it has to be a cursor FOR loop, then it depends on what you want to do in that loop, because dynamic SQL isn't easy to implement as you'd have to put EVERYTHING into dynamic SQL, and that's a nightmare to work with.